# How do you use the Element API plugin to output Assets from Matrix block for an entry?

Tags: plugin-elementapi

I have Single Section(entry) with Matrix field which contains Assets in blocks. I'm trying to fetch assets from a single Matrix block.

My `element-api.php` code is:

```
<?php

use craft\elements\Entry;
use craft\elements\MatrixBlock;
use craft\elements\Asset;
use craft\helpers\UrlHelper;

return [
  'endpoints' => [
    'api/portfolio/<blockId:\d+>.json' => function($blockId) {
      return [
        'elementType' => MatrixBlock::class,
        'criteria' => ['ownerId' => '4351', 'fieldId' => '218', 'id' => $blockId],
        'pretty' => true,
      ];
    },
  ]
];
```

Part of output is:

```
   "join": [
            [
                "INNER JOIN",
                "{{%relations}} relations",
                [
                    "and",
                    "[[relations.targetId]] = [[elements.id]]",
                    {
                        "relations.sourceId": "4402",
                        "relations.fieldId": "219"
                    },
                    [
                        "or",
                        {
                            "relations.sourceSiteId": null
                        },
                        {
                            "relations.sourceSiteId": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
```

so it looks like I'm trying to access related field id 219 which is Assets field inside Matrix block.

Fields structure:
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [transformer](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api/blob/v2/README.md#transformer)

```
'transformer' => function(MatrixBlock $element){
    return [
       'image' => $element->getFieldValue('assetFieldHandle')->one()->getUrl() 
    ];
}
```